# React Native & Typescript, how to add interface using MobX

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobx

I am trying to add an interface for todoScreen's prop but Im new to Typescript and RN so could someone help me out here? Im sure there are some errors in the code too.

I will also need to add an in-line type for 'items' in the store

```js
import { observable, computed, action } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";

class TodoStore {
  @observable
  public items = [{ title: "hire great RN dev", checked: false }];


  @computed
  public get itemCount(): number {
    return this.items.length;
  }

  @action
  public addItem = (title: string) => {
    this.items.push({ title, checked: false });
  };

  @action
  private toggleItemCheck = (index) => {
    this.items[index].checked = !this.items[index].checked;
  };
}

const todoStore = new TodoStore();

export const todoScreen: React.FC = observer((props) => {
  const { titleStringFromParent } = props;

  return (
    <View>
      <h1>{titleStringFromParent}</h1>
      {todoStore.items.map((item) => (
        <>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          <Button onPress={todoStore.toggleItemCheck}>
            {item.checked ? "uncheck" : "check"}
          </Button>
        </>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you have default items then types will be inferred automatically. But if you still want to manually add types then just type it as a regular array with objects, like that:

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  checked: boolean;
}

class TodoStore {
  @observable
  public items: Array<Item> = [{ title: "hire great RN dev", checked: false }];

  // ...
}
```